# API not available from Spring MVC controller, but is available from Java program

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

In an Eclipse project, I imported a group of jars.  The api from the jars can be called from a Java program with `public static void main` by right clicking on the class and clicking `run as java program`.  However, in the same Eclipse project, the api is not available when called through Spring MVC controllers. The complete stack trace of the error is included below. **What can I change so that the api is available in the Spring MVC controllers also?**

I have read many postings on the error message, but they all focus on whether or not the jars are included in the build path.  In this case, the jars ARE included in the buildpath.  In this case the problem is that Spring MVC cannot see the jars even though `public static void main` can see the jars.

The code from the Java program that runs correctly is as follows:

```
package publicstaticvoidmain;

import org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.ccd.CCDPackage;
import org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil;

public class MdhtTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Implicit initialization
        CDAUtil.loadPackages();
    
        // Explicit initialization
        //      CCDPackage.eINSTANCE.eClass();

        System.out.println("----------------------> MdhtTest RAN WITHOUT ANY ERRORS.  THIS IS SUCCESS!!! <-------------------------");

    }
}
```

The code in the controller class that throws the error is:

```
package controllerpackage;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import modelpackage.SomeModelClass;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes(types = SomeModelClass.class)
public class SomeModelClassController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/TriggerTheError", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
    DataFunctionsMDHT mf = new DataFunctionsMDHT();
    mf.unmarshal();
    return "ReproduceNoClassDefFoundError";
}

}
```

The complete stack trace that is thrown when the api is called from the Spring controller code is as follows:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openhealthtools/mdht/uml/cda/util/CDAUtil
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73) [datatables-core-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71) [datatables-servlet2-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openhealthtools/mdht/uml/cda/util/CDAUtil
    at controllerpackage.DataFunctionsMDHT.unmarshal(DataFunctionsMDHT.java:8) ~[DataFunctionsMDHT.class:na]
    at controllerpackage.SomeModelClassController.processFindForm(SomeModelClassController.java:19) ~[SomeModelClassController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Apr 20, 2015 8:53:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [NoClassDefFoundError] in context with path [/NoClassDefFoundError] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openhealthtools/mdht/uml/cda/util/CDAUtil] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
    at controllerpackage.DataFunctionsMDHT.unmarshal(DataFunctionsMDHT.java:8)
    at controllerpackage.SomeModelClassController.processFindForm(SomeModelClassController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Edit

Here are some repro instructions:

1.) Download the Eclipse project zip from the link above

2.) Import the Eclipse project zip into Eclipse as a new project

3.) Download the jar files zip from the second link above.

4.) Right click on the project name, then select Build Path...

5.) Add all the jars from the downloaded jar zip into the build path

6.) Right click the project name, then select Run As.. Run on Server

7.) Clicking the link on the main page in the browser will reproduce the error from the controller

8.) Right clicking on publicstaticvoidmain.MdhtTest.java and selecting Run As..Java Program will work properly

### Edit 2

As per @JBNizet's suggestion, I created a lib folder located at /WEB-INF/lib and then typed  `mv /path/to/all/the/jars/* /path/to/workspace/MyApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/`  This did move the jars to the lib folder.  I pressed F5 in eclipse to refresh the view so the jars can be seen in the folder in eclipse.  But yet the error continues to be re-created every time I click on the link that calls the controller code.

In a separate attempt, Eclipse did not allow me to use the GUI to simply copy and paste the Jars from the libraries folder into the lib folder.

Also, @JBNizet suggested [this link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), but the code at the link is not clear.  The link suggests typing `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>` but does not say where to type it.  Or when.

Note that there are over 20 jars!  Do I type `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>` 20 times, once for each jar?  And do I have to type this every time I do a `maven update`?  Do I navigate to the repository root directory to type this command?  Or to a subdirectory?

Comment: Where is the import of DataFunctionsMDHT  and CDAUtil in your Controller? Where this classes invoked by your controller?

Comment: @erhun Please see my **EDIT** to my OP.  I added two links to download a stripped down version of the eclipse project and all the required jars.  I also added explicit instructions to reproduce the error.  Does this answer your question?  Is there anything else I can provide?

Comment: @erhun I also added an **EDIT#2** to my OP.  Are you willing to help me solve this?

Comment: I have removed a dead image and two dead file links from this post, which perhaps serves as an illustration why such things should not be added to questions (images are OK though if they are uploaded to the official Stack Overflow CDN). I don't know Java well enough to decide whether this question is now lacking a [mcve], but it may be closed by folks active in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The Java build path is just that: the path used to *build* your application.

At runtime, when executed inside the web container, the necessary libraries must be available to the web application as well. To be available to the application, they must be part of the WEB-INF/lib directory of the deployed war or exploded war file.

Eclipse won't put the libraries in the *build* path into WEB-INF/lib. What it will put in WEB-INF/lib is the set of libraries located in the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib directory of your eclipse web project. And those libraries are automatically also added to the build path by eclipse.

So, remove all the libraries you need at runtime from the build path, and add them to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.

Note that your screenshot looks like the project is in fact a Maven project, and should thus be built by Maven. If that's the case, then you should not even add anything to the build path or to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib. You should instead add the dependencies to your Maven pom.xml file.

Comment: If these jars are not available via Maven, then there's no way for Maven to build the project. Choose Maven coordinates for them, add them to your own local or corporate Maven repository, and add them as dependencies to your pom. That's how Maven is supposed to be used.

Comment: Use google. Google for "how to add jars to local maven repository". And click on the first result, which is a page hosted by maven.apache.org, titled "Maven – Guide to installing 3rd party JARs". Life is much simpler when you know about google.

Comment: I added **EDIT#2** to my OP with the results of trying all of your suggestions.  Are you willing to help me with this?

Comment: Run it from wherever you want. Run it when you need to add a jar to the local maven repo. And, yes, you must do it for each jar. I have no idea what you mean by "maven update".